# Copy table to clipboard in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to copy div element to clipboard in vuejs. I have gone through to search related solution and applied. But not working. I ant to copy full table  to clipboard. Thanks in advance

```
 <button v-on:click = "copyToClipboard(select_txt)">Click To Copy</button>
                <table class="table table-sm" id="select_txt">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td> abcd </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Phone</td>
                        <td>124545</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Methods

```
 methods:{
        copyToClipboard(containerid){
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNode(containerid); 
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
            window.getSelection().addRange(range);
            document.execCommand("copy");
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
            alert("data copied");
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing something wrong in selecting node.

```
copyToClipboard(containerid){
            var range = document.createRange();
            let containerNode = document.getElementById(containerid); //// this part
            range.selectNode(containerNode); //// this part
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
            window.getSelection().addRange(range);
            document.execCommand("copy");
            window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
            alert("data copied");
        }
```

To copy html code

```
copyToClipboard(containerid) {
      let containerNode = document.getElementById(containerid);
      var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
      textArea.style.position = "fixed";
      textArea.style.top = 0;
      textArea.style.left = 0;

      // Ensure it has a small width and height. Setting to 1px / 1em
      // doesn't work as this gives a negative w/h on some browsers.
      textArea.style.width = "2em";
      textArea.style.height = "2em";

      // We don't need padding, reducing the size if it does flash render.
      textArea.style.padding = 0;

      // Clean up any borders.
      textArea.style.border = "none";
      textArea.style.outline = "none";
      textArea.style.boxShadow = "none";

      // Avoid flash of white box if rendered for any reason.
      textArea.style.background = "transparent";

      textArea.value = containerNode.outerHTML;

      document.body.appendChild(textArea);
      textArea.focus();
      textArea.select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
      window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
      document.body.removeChild(textArea);
      alert("data copied");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but it shows error **Failed to execute 'selectNode' on 'Range': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.**

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-lalande-ec5qs?file=/src/App.vue my sandbox. check this

Comment: you are doing wrong in Html side. likely you have to send a string to the function as a parameter. add quotes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working. I want to copy table with html like **<table><tr>abc</tr></table>** ..... bla bla . Can you please help me ?

Comment: var target = document.getElementById('myElement');
var wrap = document.createElement('div');
wrap.appendChild(target.cloneNode(true));
alert(wrap.innerHTML);

Comment: or this will work
var el = document.getElementById( 'foo' );
alert( el.outerHTML );

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-lalande-ec5qs?file=/src/App.vue:474-1614 check again codesandbox and I edited my answer

Comment: its my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

```
copyText() {

   var el = document.getElementById('table');

            var body = document.body,

                range,

                sel;

            if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {

                range = document.createRange();

                sel = window.getSelection();

                sel.removeAllRanges();

                try {

                    range.selectNodeContents(el);

                    sel.addRange(range);

                } catch (e) {

                    range.selectNode(el);

                    sel.addRange(range);

                }

            } else if (body.createTextRange) {

                range = body.createTextRange();

                range.moveToElementText(el);

                range.select();

            }

            document.execCommand("Copy");

    },
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).